# Nissan Key Programing

Tags: nissan, key

I have several new-ish (2011+) Nissan cars that need key work (more keys/removing lost keys).  All have the new proximity key (with the slide-out door key).

From my searching it seems that the only way to do this is with special equipment, but it seems that the equipment is available to locksmiths.
I don't want to go to the dealer or a locksmith and spend hundreds of dollars for each key.
How might I go about finding this type of programming equipment?

Comment: You need to post the exact make and model to get any help on programming. Some if not most cars don't need special equipment if you have at least one working key. Buying the programming equipment will be at least several hundred dollars.

Comment: If you are in the US, Wal-mart can program some vehicle keys. You would have to check with them about which makes and models.

Comment: In short it will be cheaper to have the dealer or locksmith program new keys for each of your vehicles than to obtain the software, subscriptions and locksmith license.

Answer (score 2):

It appears your only choice if you want to do it yourself is to purchase the [Consult III plus](http://www.buyobdtool.com/wholesale/nissan-consult-3-plus-nissan-consult-3-nissan-diagnostic-tool.html), which will do the job on all Nissan, Infinity, and GTR vehicles. This is not a cheap option, but if you need to do it for several, the cost investment may be overcome very quickly.

Comment: A caveat, on almost all newer cars (unsure of the cutoff date) you need to be a licensed locksmith to program keys into the module. You need a techinfo subscription with the manufacture as well Sadly, the days of being able to do this with just a scantool are gone. see http://lockmanlocksmiths.com/pdfs/NissanGuide.pdf for info on the process.